# error encountering during the Yocto build process (KIRKSTONE for VAR-SOM-MX6 board) ,systemd recipe failing to unpack due to a BitBake Fetcher Error

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu-22.04, yocto-project, bitbake

I'm facing an error during environment setup related to VAR-SOM-MX6 - Yocto Kirkstone 4.0 based on FSL Community BSP 4.0 with 5.15.71_2.2.0 Linux release. The terminal output is below. I have already used `git clone` and got 255-stable version.

```
endo_test_pc@endo-test-pc:~/var-fslc-yocto$ bitbake fsl-image-qt5
WARNING: You have included the meta-virtualization layer, but 'virtualization' has not been enabled in your DISTRO_FEATURES. Some bbappend files may not take effect. See the meta-virtualization README for details on enabling virtualization support.
Loading cache: 100% |########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 5215 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "var-som-mx6"
DISTRO               = "fslc-xwayland"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa9 neon thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            = "HEAD:6505459809380ddcf152a09343e4dc55038de332"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-python          
meta-filesystems     
meta-gnome           
meta-networking      = "HEAD:82c75b466e55d7dca7a2364986ecb704cf63d141"
meta-freescale       = "HEAD:d9f77788e1902a7d999958575a955e701c1c1b61"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "HEAD:f6fa0fd8783ce69d07feaad0b7ca6759b5a4d5d6"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:d5bbb487b2816dfc74984a78b67f7361ce404253"
meta-freescale-ml    = "HEAD:e86f4ac6ed3c18c1ed3dd76824fda4dd0e8c4f8d"
meta-clang           = "HEAD:c728c3f9168c8a4ed05163a51dd48ca1ad8ac21d"
meta-chromium        = "HEAD:e232c2e21b96dc092d9af8bea4b3a528e7a46dd6"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:aec1934cb2708236c033f2d205d5c3fbbebf7555"
meta-python2         = "HEAD:f02882e2aa9279ca7becca8d0cedbffe88b5a253"
meta-swupdate        = "HEAD:91de63c006e886eba8d9c263c9aa55d4c7632072"
meta-virtualization  = "HEAD:a7413c5d7568ce91b809ed11f84305b1afb468bb"
meta-variscite-bsp   = "HEAD:83aa4f12e0e82b19993be5fb872ae13db1095f94"
meta-variscite-sdk   = "HEAD:398f30f5d6b9f11d09dd3285baf5158ceb36599b"
meta-variscite-hab   = "HEAD:7784b74fe02331175fbb11ac7e7efd50d30a5fd1"

Initialising tasks: 100% |###################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:07
Sstate summary: Wanted 3142 Local 0 Mirrors 0 Missed 3142 Current 383 (0% match, 10% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: systemd-1_250.5-r0 do_unpack: Bitbake Fetcher Error: UnpackError('No up to date source found: clone directory not available or not up to date: /opt/yocto_downloads//git2/github.com.systemd.systemd-stable.git; shallow clone not enabled', 'git://github.com/systemd/systemd-stable.git;protocol=https;branch=v250-stable')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/endo_test_pc/var-fslc-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/systemd/1_250.5-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.200951
ERROR: Task (/home/endo_test_pc/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_250.5.bb:do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1334 tasks of which 1323 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
NOTE: Writing buildhistory took: 8 seconds

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/endo_test_pc/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_250.5.bb:do_unpack
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

please provide possible fix for this problem.